# why bootstrap do not have access to view obtained on tab clicked on _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working mvc-5 and using bootstrap and all my links are in  `_Layout.cshtml` now i have a drop down tabs like this http://prntscr.com/76jfba (using bootstrap, It is obtained on VStudio project launch) now in my
`_Layout.cshtml` I have `renderbody()` which renders all my UI .

**What I want to do**

On clicking the tab "Real Time" I get a dropdown list which on futher click to "Tabular" must open replace the current view just below the tabs to a new view .

**How I tried to do this**

(1) In home controller I do this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace testLayt.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult tabularshared()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

(2) Then I create view and in that view I add Layout path like this :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "shekharTabularshared";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>tabularshared</h2>
```

As a result I have all the tabs but they are not aligned properly. It now shows the view like this: http://prntscr.com/76jiag
I feel like I dont have access to bootstrap here or I am doing anything wrong ?

Could some one please give guidance such that I can have `tabular.cshtml` view just below the tab in the first link (this tab will be common to all the views obtained)

EDIT: _Layout.cshtml

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <!--starts here-->   
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!--click on main tab disappers--> 


    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <!--ends here-->
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" @Html.ActionLink("Vision Vertex", "Index", "Home") />
                                </div>

                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                Real Time
                                                <i class="caret"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                                        
                                                <li>
                                                    <!--onclick="tabularFunction()" -->
                                                    @*<a tabindex="-1" href="~/Views/Home/BackgroundViews/tabular.cshtml">Tabular</a>*@
                                                    @Html.ActionLink("Tabular", "tabularshared", "Home")
                                                </li>                                                
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>        
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and Index.cshtml is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

<h2>shekhar Index</h2>
```

Further i noticed that on clicking at "Tabular" when i do "Inspect elements" i do not have    `<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` it's surprising for and i am stuck here since 3 last days. Could someone please help me?

**Here is my full project i really appreciate if you could please help me coming out of this problem** https://www.dropbox.com/sh/autm3mkqfdu0aup/AADfAeUSlvcDt7PTX8G5Qz9La?dl=0

Comment: Have you included the relevant bootstrap css files?

Comment: I have included all in _Layout.cshtml (in order to have my down drop-able tabs at top must remain common for every view loaded below these tabs, As we have Home, About and Contact in basic MVC msdn sample). But i have just included all my css and JS links in _Layout.cshtml but not in tabular.cshtml. DO i need to add them in tabular.cshtml ? How to include there if Yes ?

Comment: My tabular.cshtml just contain the code i have shown in point (2) and  the UI obtained is shown here http://prntscr.com/75qxaz (which shows all tabs in text for but no UI allignment).

Comment: can you show us your _Layout.cshtml file?

Comment: Can you show all window in a screenshot, not only your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference on how you render your UI.

1. Make sure there are no errors in your developer console (you might wrongly
   configure your bundles for bootstrap scripts).
2. Left only one reference to bootstrap CSS:

   href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"
3. Inspect in developer console that all scripts&styles are actually loaded to the page.

   If nothing wrong but your code still not works - add a full screenshot of your web-page in browser and let me know in comments.

You have lost **'~'** symbols in your bootsrap CSS links.

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please see my edited question. I dont know why css is not loaded in tabularshared.cshtml view on inspecting.

Comment: @ajpr, see edited answer. If it not helps, please upload your project to any free file storage and give me it's link.

Comment: please see this link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/autm3mkqfdu0aup/AADfAeUSlvcDt7PTX8G5Qz9La?dl=0

Comment: Like a said the problem is that your links lack '~' symbol in '_Layout.cshtml' file. See this: http://www.filedropper.com/testlayt

Comment: i just solved the problem.. Please do not mind previous comment. Thanks for the answer